# Python code vs BBC Basic for Windows

Tags: python, basic

How would I be able to improve the speed of this monty hall program, interestingly, the same code written using BBC BASIC for Windows completes the task in half the time of the Python code.

Python Code:

```python
import random

t = 10000001
j = 0
k = 0

for a in range(1, t):
    p = int(random.random() * 3) + 1
    g = int(random.random() * 3) + 1

    if p == g:
        r = int(random.random() * 2) + 1
        if p == 1:
            r += 1
        if p == 2 and r == 2:
            r = 3
    else:
        r = p ^ g
    s = g
    f = g ^ r
    if s == p:
        j = j + 1
    if f == p:
        k = k + 1

print(f"After a total of {t - 1} trials,")
print(f"The 'sticker' won {j} times ({int(j/t*100)}%)")
print(f"The 'swapper' won {k} times ({int(k/t*100)}%)")
```

BBC BASIC for Windows code

```
T% = 10000000

for A% = 1 to T%
  P% = rnd(3)
  G% = rnd(3)
  if P% = G% then

    R% = rnd(2)
    if P% = 1 then R% += 1
    if P% = 2 and R% = 2 then R% = 3
  else
    R% = P% eor G%
  endif
  S% = G%
  F% = G% eor R%
  if S% = P% then J% = J% + 1
  if F% = P% then K% = K% + 1
next

print "After a total of ";T%;" trials,"
print "The 'sticker' won ";J%;" times (";int(J%/T%*100);"%)"
print "The 'swapper' won ";K%;" times (";int(K%/T%*100);"%)"
```

Comment: Are you asking for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of code review

Answer (score 1):

First thing is changing your import from:

```
import random
```

to

```
from random import random
```

then using:

```
p = int(random() * 3) + 1
g = int(random() * 3) + 1
```

Second thing you can do is change your:

```
if s == p:
     j = j + 1
if f == p:
     k = k + 1
```

Into:

```
if s == p:
     j = j + 1
elif f == p:
     k = k + 1
```